# Contemplating about API design of a typescript/nodejs library for querying a remote storage service

Tags: javascript, api-design

I am working on a Typescript library (to be used by many users within my org, possibly open-sourced) which provides access to some remote storage. I am contemplating between several variants for the main methods. Let's take the "query" method as an example. Here are several alternatives for its signature:

```
// alternative (a) - pass a single object (named arguments)
const items[] = await client.query({
    expression: "a1 = :v1",
    filter: "a2 > :v2"
    values: {v1: 'foo', v2: 'bar'}, 
    timeoutMs: 100,
    numItems: 3, 
    consistency: "STRONG"})

// alternative (b) - pass multiple values (positional arguments)
const items[] = await client.query("a1 = :v1", "a2 > :v2", 
    {v1: 'foo', v2: 'bar'}, 100, 3, "STRONG")

// alternative (c), split to to two methods,
//   pass positional arguments
const items[] = client.query("a1 = :v1", "a2 > :v2",
    {v1: 'foo', v2: 'bar'})
    .fetch(100, 3, "STRONG")

// alternative (d) - split to two methods
//   pass positional arguments to the former, named to the latter 
const items[] = client.query("a1 = :v1", "a2 > :v2", 
    {v1: 'foo', v2: 'bar'})
    .fetch({timeoutMs: 100, numItems: 3, consistency: "STRONG"})

// alternative (e) - split to two methods, 
//   pass positional arguments to both 
const items[] = client.query({
    expression: "a1 = :v1",
    filter: "a2 > :v2"
    values: {v1: 'foo', v2: 'bar'})
    .fetch({timeoutMs: 100, numItems: 3, consistency: "STRONG"})
```

(there probably other alternatives one can think of...)

### Contemplation #1

In order to perform a query should the call site call a single method (`query()` - as shown in (a), (b)) or two methods (`query()` followed by `fetch()` - as shown in (c), (d), (e)).

calling a single method is conceptually simpler. OTOH, splitting it to two makes it easy for users of the library to perform "chunk processing": read 10 items, inspect them, read 20 more, inspect them, read some more, etc.

### Contemplation #2

named vs. positional? (in either the `query()` or `fetch()` methods)

named arguments are more explicit and make it easier to pass any subset of the optional arguments. On the other hand, the call sites are more verbose  which is often a major deterring factor.

Answer (score 1):

A and B suffer from an issue you already pointed out, which is that you can't reuse the query to do incremental processing. It also splits up the implementation into meaningful parts: generating the query via `query()` and getting the results via `fetch()`.

When deciding between positional vs. named arguments there are a few considerations:

1. **How many arguments does a function have?** Once functions start to have more than 3-4 arguments it becomes a bit unwieldy to keep track of each one. The added verbosity of named arguments helps.
2. **Are any of the arguments optional?** Optional positional arguments are a pain to work with when there is more than one optional arg, especially when the default for the argument is something other than null/false.
3. **Will you ever add or remove arguments?** If this seems like a hard question to answer, you may want to consider named arguments.

Using a `fetch()` method eliminates any concerns for #1.

For #2, it seems like there are some reasonable defaults you could apply to the `fetch()` method. Named arguments here make a lot of sense.

So, assuming we use named args for `fetch()`, that just leaves `query()`. Whether you are adding or removing arguments here is something you need to decide. You've reached a fair compromise by mixing both named and positional args for `query()` which is the right choice.

With all that said, alternative D seems like the best option. For the other alternatives, I find myself asking questions like, "Why am I writing so much?", "What does this argument do?", "Why isn't the timeout set on the client?", etc.